# oozie Coordinator for Historic dates

Tags: hadoop, hive, oozie, oozie-coordinator

I want to run oozie coordinator for historic dates and pass date as parameter to a script in workflow. How do I do that?

Can I put start date as old date ? Will it catch up? and what frequency should I add to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, when you submit a coordinator with start date in the past it catches up. It starts the execution immediately so setting concurrency=1 saves your cluster from heavy load. You can also set execution=LIFO if you want to process new files first. For more info look into http://oozie.apache.org/docs/3.3.2/CoordinatorFunctionalSpec.html

I'm posting a modified sample from the answer to [How to schedule a sqoop action using oozie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18118342/how-to-schedule-a-sqoop-action-using-oozie)

Create coordinator.xml file:

```
<coordinator-app name="sample-coord" xmlns="uri:oozie:coordinator:0.2"

                 frequency="${coord:days(7)}"
                 start="${start}"
                 end=  "${end}"

                 timezone="America/New_York">

    <controls>
        <timeout>${timeout}</timeout>
        <concurrency>1</concurrency>
    </controls>

    <datasets>
        <dataset name="data"
                 frequency="${coord:days(7)}"
                 initial-instance="${start}" timezone="America/New_York">
            <uri-template>${data_path}/${YEAR}/${MONTH}/${DAY}</uri-template>
            <done-flag/>
        </dataset>
    </datasets>

    <input-events>
        <data-in name="data_in" dataset="data">
            <instance>${coord:current(0)}</instance>
        </data-in>
    </input-events>

    <action>
        <workflow>
            <app-path>${wf_application_path}</app-path>

            <configuration>
                <property>
                    <name>input</name>
                    <value>${coord:dataIn('data_in')}</value>
                </property>
            </configuration>
        </workflow>
    </action>
</coordinator-app>
```

Specify all properties used in the above file in coordinator.properties:

```
host=namenode01
nameNode=hdfs://${host}:8020

wf_application_path=${nameNode}/oozie/deployments/example
oozie.coord.application.path=${wf_application_path}

data_path=${nameNode}/data

start=2013-08-01T01:00Z
end=2013-08-19T23:59Z
timeout=10
```

Upload your coordinator.xml file to hdfs and then submit your coordinator job with something like

```
oozie job -config coordinator.properties -run
```