# Sqoop. Importing data into date based directories

Tags: sqoop

I am writing a sqoop command which will be converted into a sqoop job. However I want the job to create a new directory every day. so for example when the import job runs yesterday it should create directory path /2015/11/09 and then today /2015/11/10.

Can squoop do this? or should I generate the sqoop command to be run on a daily basic with appropriate directory structure dynamically created?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I found the answer to my question. We ended up using Oozie to schedule our Sqoop command.

We can pass arguments to sqoop from Oozie and oozie gives us a expression language from which we can dynamically create the target-dir string.

I guess in the end whichever technology is being used to schedule the job, that will be resonsible for building out the target-dir param.

Comment: can you please provide the example

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18118342/how-to-schedule-a-sqoop-action-using-oozie